# CFEclipse:- Auto Complete,keyboard shortcuts and toolbar icons not working

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, cfeclipse

I have CFEclipse-Java/Release 3.6.1  installed on my sys(Coldfusion-8/Windows XP professional)
I am facing the following problems:-

```
1) Auto code Complete of tags, is not working
2) the code hint for tags is not working
3)The icons on the toolbars such as <cfdump>,<cfscript>,<cfoutput>,##,"" etc are also not working.
4)many commands such as "Cntr+Alt+m" for commenting is not working.
```

I closed and reopened the .exe file.also Restarted the sys,but in vain.

OBSERVATION:-
Some times when i open an js/css/cfc file along with the .cfm files the say Home.cfm,

and then try to use  "//" etc from the  toolbar icons
these tags will come across "js/css/cfc" files but not in the .cfm files.

Please help.

-Vas

Comment: It might help to mention what versions of: CFEclipse and Eclipse

Comment: CFEclipse-Java/Release 3.6.1 installed on my sys(Coldfusion-8/Windows XP professional)

Comment: Are you using the CFE Nature on the Project?

Comment: No I am not using CFE nature.

Comment: ...and, if you do, does it fix any or all of your issues?

Answer (score 2):

I feel that SO is not fully appropriate place to report such kind of software issues... It looks like you have problems with whole plugin installation.

So I propose you to visit [CFEclipse Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/cfeclipse-users/) where you might find the workarounds for your issues (use search) and ask CFEclipse developers (they are pretty friendly).